# function that the user inputs coordinates x,y and find if the coordinates are inside the area of an given rectangle c

Tags: c, function, geometry

```
#include <stdio.h>
char dentroRetangulo(int v1x, int v1y, int v2x, int v2y, int x, int y);
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, f,d,g,x,y;
    char D, h;
    
    printf("== Coordinates of a rectangle ==\n");
    printf("Inform the coordinates of the left inferior corner : \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("Inform the coordinates of the superior right corner: \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &c, &d);
    printf("=== points ===\n");
    printf("inform the coordinates of the point (x,y)\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &f, &g);
    h = dentroRetangulo(a,b,c,d,f,g);
    
    if(h == D)
    {
        printf("O ponto(%d, %d) encontra-se dentro  do retangulo", x, y);
    }
    
        return 0;
}
    
char dentroRetangulo(int v1x, int v1y, int v2x, int v2y, int x, int y)
{
    char D;
    char B;
    char F;
    if(x>v1x && x<v2x || y> v1y && y<v2y)
    {
        return D;
    }
```

so basically, this function is about of checking if a point is inside of a rectangle with the inferior corner x,y coordinates being v1x  and v1y, and the superior coordinates v2x and v2y, and in the main function the user is supposed to input  x and y coordinates to verify if they are inside it, i'm kinda of a newbie in C, but i already lost 1 entire day trying to find out what i did wrong here and idk maybe i'm too stupid to not see what is going on wrong here

Comment: so the function check if the statement is true and return a D value, to the main function, and if the h ==  D the char that returns from the function, the if statement checks it and print the point its inside the rectangle, sorry i'm brazilian, and i forgot to translate the last printf

Comment: What makes you think that you did something wrong? What are the symptoms? What do you observe? What behaviour do you want?

Comment: You have 2 `D` variables and I don't see where either one is given a value.

Comment: Also, `if(x>v1x && x<v2x || y> v1y && y<v2y)` should have `&&` where you have `||` since you want _all_ conditions to be true.

Comment: Seems you didn't post all the code

Comment: The "||" OR-operator is wrong for this check, it should be "&&".

Comment: You should set a value for the variable `D`, e.g. `char D = 'd';`

Comment: @Ripi2 nah... it shouldn't be used at all

Comment: The function `dentroRetangulo` should return a `bool`. Return `true` if the point is inside the rectangle, return `false` if the point is not inside the rectangle. Then the `if` statement in `main` is `if (dentroRetangulo(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)) printf("dentro\n");`

Comment: Have you considered using a `struct` to define a rectangle? The result is a cleaner and easier to understand code: https://ideone.com/HhVvVo

Comment: i posted my code after editing and finding the answer that i was looking for, i hope it can be useful to other persons who have the same problem

Comment: @FaustinoDaSilva Don't update the question with the "fixed" code... If you want you can post your fixed code as answer but don't change the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code has some issues, but the main problem seems to arise from some basic misunderstandings.

```c
// The following will declare, but WON'T initialize two variables
// of type 'char'. Here, D, is the NAME of the variable, not its content,
// which is indeterminated.
char D, h; 

// Here h is assigned the value returned by OP's function, which has the 
// exact same issue noted before. Its value will still remain indeterminated.
h = /* ... */;

// Comparing two variables with indeterminated values has undefined behavior.
if ( h == D ) { /* ... */ }
```

If the intent is to write a function that returns a `char` value of `'D'` when a point is inside a rectangle or `'F'` otherwise (maybe `'B'` if it's on one of the edges), the following could be a possible implementation.

```c
typedef struct point_s
{
    int x, y;
} Point;

char point_rectangle_intersection(Point bottom_left, Point top_right, Point p)
{
    // Check if the point is outside.
    if ( p.x < bottom_left.x  ||  p.x > top_right.x  ||
         p.y < bottom_left.y  ||  p.y > top_right.y )
        return 'F';
    
    // Check if the point is on one of the edges.
    if ( p.x == bottom_left.x  ||  p.x == top_right.x  ||
         p.y == bottom_left.y  ||  p.y == top_right.y )
        return 'B';

    // The point is inside.
    return 'D';    
}
```

Comment: wow the last part is even better than mine, you actually reduced a line of code, by just returning what is inside

Comment: sorry, its because i'm new here and i got a little confused, i dind't know that you can answer your own question

Comment: if ( h == D )  it was a misunderstanding by my part, actually the code had to return what you typed in there,  for example if the code  if h == 'D'  it would say that the coordinate lies inside the rectangle, and so on, i was thinking that it was supposed to be another thing

Comment: i marked you as answers, because you did the job to understand why i was struggling and got some sense out of it, i alredy solved my own problem, btw but you are the one that actually got the most close of solving thx

Answer (score 1):

You are trying too much in a single line... this one is too complex:

```
if(x>v1x && x<v2x || y> v1y && y<v2y)
```

and it's also wrong. It should be:

```
if(x>v1x && x<v2x && y> v1y && y<v2y)
```

But avoid such statements...

Keep things simple by writing more code lines.

But first notice that a function like this should return `0` (aka false) when the point is outside  and `1` (aka true) when it's inside.

So to keep it simple do:

```
int dentroRetangulo(int v1x, int v1y, int v2x, int v2y, int x, int y)
{
    if (x < v1x) return 0;  // If the point is to the left, return 0
    if (x > v2x) return 0;  // If the point is to the rigth, return 0
    if (y < v1y) return 0;  // If the point is below, return 0
    if (y > v2y) return 0;  // If the point is above, return 0

    return 1; // The point is inside, return 1
}
```

One simple check on each line makes your code more simple.

And in `main` call it like

```
if(dentroRetangulo(a,b,c,d,f,g))
{
    printf("O ponto(%d, %d) encontra-se dentro  do retangulo", f, g);
}
```

Comment: yeah, but its against my first question, and you repeat if to many times, my question was a way of returning the character D, wich i found in my main code, and the second line was wrong, because i edited the code without knowing it

Comment: i said its against my first question because i don't want to return a integer 1, i want to return a character D

Comment: @FaustinoDaSilva So you want to return the character `D` when the point is inside, correct? And which character do you want when it is outside?

Comment: i want to return F